# Как дописать в файл байты?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть уже созданный файл с информацией, если мне нужно дописать в него еще пару строк, то согласно документации там написано так

> Когда выходной файл открыт, любой ранее существовавший файл с тем же именем уничтожается.

Значит если нужно дописать строки в существующий файл, то нужно открыть входной поток, записать все из существующего файла куда нибудь в буфер, потом добавить в его то, что нужно и записать новый файл?

Или есть более ровные решения?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вы наверное замечали, что FileOutputStream имеет расширение boolean append.

> True if the file is opened for append.

true, если файл открыт для добавления.

```
try (FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file, true)) {
    output.write(data);
}
```

...

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
try {
   output.write(data);
} 
finally {
   output.close();
}
```

Comment: Булево значение `true` переводится на русский язык как `истина`. Перевод `правда` - некорректный.

Comment: Дело не в переводе как раз, но вы правы, данный перевод не корректный.